# How to solve sql query in where clause

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

How to solve sql query with where clause that i have data

```
TranID HotelID FacilityID
7      1        4
9      1        8
12     2        4
13     2        8
19     9        4
229    2        8
244    74       8
```

i want to display like this, where Hotel ID will be same for different FacilityID

```
TranID HotelID FacilityID
7      1        4
9      1        8
12     2        4
13     2        8
```

so please help me thanks in advance

Comment: on what criteria u want to select?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f4b5 check this fiddle

Comment: @VIPULPARMAR http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9103/37 see if this is fine & let me know

Comment: @NEHA http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82849/1 check this in that the data of my table. Hotel ID is unique. And this is my query
Select DISTINCT h.*,c.CityName from ((MST_Hotel h INNER JOIN MST_City c on h.City=c.CityID) INNER JOIN MST_FacilityTran ft on ft.HotelID=h.HotelID) where ft.FacilityID IN (4,8)

Comment: after where clause i want to put conditions so how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select * from [My-table]
where HotelID in (1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
SELECT t1.*
    FROM tableHotel t1
    WHERE EXISTS
    (
    SELECT 1 FROM tableHotel t2
    WHERE t2.HotelID= t1.HotelID
    AND t2.FacilityID <> t1.FacilityID
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM [YourTable]
WHERE TranID IN (7,9,12,13)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from table where HotelID IN (1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

it solved 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82849/46

```
SELECT DISTINCT h.*,c.CITY
    FROM MST_FacilityTrans t1
     INNER JOIN MST_HOTEL h on h.HotelID=t1.HotelID
    INNER JOIN MST_City c on h.CityID=c.CityID 
    WHERE EXISTS
    (
    SELECT 1 FROM MST_FacilityTrans t2
    WHERE t2.HotelID= t1.HotelID
    AND t2.FacilityID <> t1.FacilityID
    )
```